# Solr - How to change the default core for Healthcheck

Tags: solr

I am working with Solr 4.7.1

With a fresh installation, the following link:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping
```

Only works when core collection1 exists in the following folder hierarchy:
/example/solr/collection1

I have created a new core: collection2

I want this link to work when I replace core collection1 with core collection2:
/example/solr/collection2

Problem:
When I replace collection1 with collection2, the following link gives me error 404:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping
```

It seems collection1 is set as a default somewhere. But I don't know how to change it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i tried using this url instead of solr/admin/ping. It seems to work fine

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/admin/ping`

in your case, you might want to change it to collection2 in the url above and try.

Comment: You are correct. The link you provided would work. But I need the default link to work with my new core:     http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping

Comment: You might have to customize the solr web.xml to point `/solr/admin/ping` to `solr/collectoin2/ping`.  you might want to apache HTTPD/or any webserver proxy to point it to the right resource in solr.

Answer (score 0):

To change default core names in Solr 4.x you need to define them in `solr.xml` which should be placed in your Solr `solr.home`. Here is example:

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
  <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
  <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
 </cores>
</solr>
```

In Solr 5.x you can simple create a [`core.properties`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+core.properties) anywhere under `solr.home` and it should be discovered automatically and define the name by:

```
name=my_core_name
```

Then double check your other XML Solr configuration files that you don't hardcode any old names within the files it-self.